# Ray - plane instersection , Distance from the point to the plane along the ray

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projection

I spent hours thinking and finding a way to do this.

Let's say I have a point $P(X_0,Y_0,Z_0)$ and a plane $(Ax+By+Cz+D = 0)$. I'm trying to project the point, P to the plane from the origin and get the distance between P and the projected point Q.
Is there a way to find the distance rather than finding the projected point and then Euclidean distance?

I know, if the projection is along the normal of the plane, then the distance is

Distance  $=\frac{AX_0+BY_0+CZ_0+D}{\sqrt{ A^2 +B^2 +C^2}}$

But how about along the ray.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by _projecting the point, P to the plane from the origin_? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I have attached an image. can you please see that.  the origin, point P and point Q in the same line.. but it is not perpendicular to the plane.

Comment: OK so point $Q$ is intersection point of the plane and the line through $OP$?

Comment: yes.. Q is the intersection..  you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Assuming $P$ is not on the plane, $PH$ is the minimum distance between point $P$ and the plane (which is along the normal vector).

You know the unit normal vector to the plane is,

$ \displaystyle \hat n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2}} (A, B, C)$

You also know the unit vector along $\vec {OP}$,

$\hat {p}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_0^2 + y_0^2 + z_0^2}} (x_0, y_0, z_0)$

Now using dot product you can find angle $\theta$ marked in the diagram,

$\cos\theta = |\hat {n} \cdot \hat p| $

Also, $|PQ| \cos\theta = |PH|$

You already know how to find $|PH|$ and you know $\cos\theta$.

Comment: Great.. Thank you @Math Lover for your time..  I'll accept the answer..